# Блокировка клавиатурного ввода при работе с FSI

Tags: wpf, f#

Если запускать окно в FSI (F# Interactive) следующим образом:

```
let win = new Window()
...
win.Show()
```

то клавиатурный ввод будет заблокирован. Вставка из буфера, табуляция, обработка кликов и так далее работает.

Если открывать с помощью `Application`:

```
let app = new Application()
let win = new Window()
...
app.Run win
|> ignore
```

то клавиатурный ввод будет доступен.

**Обновление**

Если открывать как диалоговое окно, то ввод также будет разрешен:

```
win.ShowDialog()
```

Вопрос: в чем причина такового поведения?

Comment: клавиатурный ввод куда? в FSI?

Comment: @Grundy нет, конечно. Например, в текстбокс приложения